# Counting duplicated Data on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table like that without row_number column,

```
acct_id     part_id   sub_model   row_number
111         201301      A            1
111         201302      A            2
111         201303      B            1
111         201304      B            2 
111         201305      C            1
111         201306      C            2
111         201307      C            3
111         201308      A            1
111         201309      A            2
111         201310      A            3
111         201311      A            4
222         201301      B            1
222         201302      B            2
222         201303      C            1
222         201304      C            2
```

and so on.
I want to add row_number column whenever a model has changed for the Acct_ID, row number will start from 1 and count till there is a change in model. 
Row_numbers of different acct_IDs shouldn't effect each other. So row_number should count and start again for a specific ID. If next acct_ID starts with same model with last row of previous acct_ID, it should notice and start from 1 again. 
This is easy to do in excel, at least for me. But data is over a million row. So I have to handle it with SQL and no idea how to do it.

Comment: is it mySQL or is it SQL Server?

Comment: could you add an sql fiddle? that would make it easier to try some stuff: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Let's start first with why you need this.  Adding this sort of "counting" field to a *relational* database table when it is not a unique index is a bit of an anti-pattern.  You already have the part_id which is unique it appears.  What value is this additional field going to give you? Also your example is unclear.  Why would part_id values between 201308 and 201311 have row_value numbers of 1234 instead of 3456 as a continuation of similar acct_id, sub_model combination shown in first two rows.  You have not really explained the true underlying logic to how this row_number field is created.

Comment: @Jester here is sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5d2e

Comment: What does your question have to do with counting duplicated data?   There are no duplicates in the sample data you are showing.

Comment: To continue my comment, you have to understand that in a relational database table that there is no guarantee of order unless you specifically note in a query that you want to order query results in some manner.  It seems like you might be under the misperception that the ordering of rows in a table as shows up in some DB viewing tool are the actual order.  That is not the case.  Here to actually order these rows you would like need to have an order by clause like `ORDER BY acct_id, sub_model, part_id` (more general to most specific). This would lead to problem noted above with sequence.

Comment: I aim two things for initial analysis. First, I'll see which submodels followed by which submodels. Second is, I'll take some models which are duplicated 6 times without anybreak. Part_ID are actually considerable as Year and months. 
And row numbers are started from 1 because model has changed on 201308.

Comment: Yes, but what is row number used for  I am guessing that you are thinking that a relational database table is like a spreadsheet, which it is not. These sorts of counting implementations (or generally being able to look at previous and next rows in addition to current row) are not part of base functionality on many relational DB's, and if those functionalities do exist, often come at price of performance. I think you need to really state how you are going to use this information in your application. If this is just to add a label on a webpage, this might be logic best left in the view layer.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I will use this data to see which models are followed by which models, how many times and etc. Also to find for example, how many times, Model_A repeated 6 times or more with a sequence. @MikeBrant

Comment: @KamranFarzami - It is SQL server.

Comment: A count would be easily doable and it might be acceptable for you as well, this would show as: 111         201301      A            2
111         201302      A            2    ..... for the first 2 rows

Comment: Can you explain more? I just couldnt follow you. @Jester

Comment: i have some trouble with your example, you have acct_id = 111 2 times model A in a row, then some other Models and then 4 times A again, but it doesn't continue the counting from 2 because of what reason? because Model B is inbetween?

Comment: @Jester - Yes, exactly. So that I can easily find which model repeated how many times in a sequence. If it would continue counting, It would be harder to get the data. If I can do that, only thing that I should do is select * where row_number = 6, for instance.

Comment: @ali, guessing my answer doesn't help then :p so the part_id's are always counting up then i'm guessing?

Comment: @Jester - Yes we can assume that, because we can ascend it :)

Comment: @ali i don't see any reasonable way to do this in sql, you're going to have (and want to) do it in php or whatever language you're coding in.

Comment: @Jester it is an sql server. How can I use php or python on this data? remember, data is about 5 million rows.

Comment: you can make a connection to a sql in server in php (don't know too much about python) but yeah it's going to be a bit slower, but i really don't see another way to get what you want. You should've probably kept track of this from the start if you wanted it. maybe it's possible but i don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my suggestion ([sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5d2e/4/0)):

```
SELECT T1.*,
   T2.row_number
FROM Table1 AS T1
JOIN (
SELECT  acct_id,
            part_id,
            sub_model,
            COUNT(*) AS row_number
FROM Table1
GROUP BY acct_id, sub_model) AS T2 ON T2.acct_id = T1.acct_id AND T2.sub_model = T1.sub_model
ORDER BY T1.acct_id, T1.part_id, T1.sub_model
```

I'm summing up the amount of times on sub_model has been used on a acct_id.
I have no idea whether this information is actually what you are looking for, if not i think Mike Brant is correct in saying this is better done in the view layer in php or whatever language you are using.